# WPF ListView bound to collection - find parent expander

Tags: wpf, data-binding, expander, collectionviewsource

I've writing an app that displays a list of drawings, as a test I've written a small app that displays how I envisage it working.

The app works by:

- Creating a BrowserItem class, this has a name property, active property and three levels of grouping.
- Has a WPF ListView which is bound to an ObservableCollection, and uses an ICollectionView to display the BrowserItems in the list view nested based on the three levels of grouping
- When the app runs, it creates several BrowserItems, sets their names and grouping etc and displays the items in the ListView

This all works well.

As a test the app has a slider which depending on the slider number simply set the Active property of a BrowserItem to true - this causes it to be highlighted in green in the list view as Active is a bound property to the font background.

What I would like to happen is when its highlighted in green, the routine will automatically expand all Expanders so the user can see the highlighted item without having to hunt for it.

Is there any way I can get the Browser items parent expander?

The code can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MW-v2gqFtubhnZdKUYGglQLN3S5xnVB4/view?usp=sharing

BrowserItem Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ListBoxTest3
{

    public partial class BrowserItem : ViewModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// BrowserItem represents a node on the browser treeview structure and relates to either a browser branch or a view / sheet
        /// </summary>

        //Group one nesting level
        private string _l1group;
        public string L1group
        {
            get
            {
                return _l1group;
            }
             set
            {
                _l1group = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(L1group));
            }
        }

        //Group two nesting level
        private string _l2group;
        public string L2group
        {
            get
            {
                return _l2group;
            }
            set
            {
                _l2group = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(L2group));
            }
        }

        //Group three nesting level
        private string _l3group;
        public string L3group
        {
            get
            {
                return _l3group;
            }
            set
            {
                _l3group = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(L3group));
            }
        }


        //Name
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
                }
            }
        }


        //Active or _active = is bound to the active view highlight
        private bool _active;

        public bool Active
        {
            get => _active;
            set
            {
                if (value != _active)
                {
                    _active = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Active));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxTest3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxTest3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="400">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Margin="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="Filter: " />
                    <TextBox x:Name="FilterBoxText"
                             Width="330"
                             Text="{Binding BrowserItemFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="Change Active to number: " />
                        <Slider x:Name="changeactive"
                                Width="210"
                                SmallChange="1"
                                ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"
                                IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                                TickFrequency="1"
                                TickPlacement="Both">

                        </Slider>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="displayslider"
                                   Text="0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListView Name="TreeViewSheets"
                      Margin="10,10,10,10"
                      Height="314"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding BrowserItemCollectionView}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}"
                                                         Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                        Value="YellowGreen" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </WrapPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>

                                            <Expander>

                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander>

                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>

            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind MainWindow.xaml:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace ListBoxTest3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MainWindowViewModel store
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            store = new MainWindowViewModel();

            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Level 01 Plan", L1group = "Architectural", Active = true, L2group = "Floor Plans", L3group = "1:100" }); ;
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Level 01 Plan", L1group = "Structural", Active = false, L2group = "Floor Plans", L3group = "1:20" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Level 02 Plan", L1group = "Architectural", Active = false, L2group = "Floor Plans", L3group = "1:100" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Level 02 Plan", L1group = "Structural", Active = false, L2group = "Floor Plans", L3group = "1:100" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Elevation East", L1group = "Architectural", Active = false, L2group = "Elevations", L3group = "1:100" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Elevation West", L1group = "Architectural", Active = false, L2group = "Elevations", L3group = "1:20" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Elevation North", L1group = "Architectural", Active = false, L2group = "Elevations", L3group = "1:100" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Section A-A", L1group = "Architectural", Active = false, L2group = "Sections", L3group = "1:100" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Section B-B", L1group = "Architectural", Active = false, L2group = "Sections", L3group = "1:100" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Section C-C", L1group = "Structural", Active = false, L2group = "Sections", L3group = "1:100" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Main Section", L1group = "Structural", Active = false, L2group = "Main Sections", L3group = "1:100" });
            store.Browser.Add(new BrowserItem() { Name = "Level 01 RCP", L1group = "Architectural", Active = false, L2group = "Ceiling Plans", L3group = "1:100" });

            TreeViewSheets.DataContext = store;

            FilterBoxText.DataContext = store;

            //Set slider max value
            changeactive.Maximum = store.Browser.Count() - 1;
        }

        private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            //When slider is moved, set the item in the list as active
            for (int f=0; f < store.Browser.Count; f++)
            {
                if (f == changeactive.Value)
                {
                    store.Browser[f].Active = true;
                    displayslider.Text = f.ToString();
                    TreeViewSheets.ScrollIntoView(store.Browser[f]);
                }
                else
                {
                    store.Browser[f].Active = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel class, this contains the ObservableCollection that contains the browser items. It also has a constructor for MainWindowViewModel that groups using a CollectionViewSource - this dynamically creates the group expanders for the Listview based on the L1Group, L2Group and L3Group fields of the BrowserItem class:

```
    class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICollectionView BrowserItemCollectionView { get; }

    private ObservableCollection<BrowserItem> _browser = new ObservableCollection<BrowserItem>();

    public ObservableCollection<BrowserItem> Browser
    {
        get => _browser;
        set
        {
            if (value != _browser)
            {
                _browser = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Browser));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _browserItemFilter = string.Empty;
    public string BrowserItemFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return _browserItemFilter;
        }
        set
        {
            _browserItemFilter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BrowserItemFilter));
            BrowserItemCollectionView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    //Constructor
    {
        BrowserItemCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_browser);

        //Set up filter
        BrowserItemCollectionView.Filter = FilterBrowserItems;

        //Set up grouping
        BrowserItemCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(BrowserItem.L1group)));
        BrowserItemCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(BrowserItem.L2group)));
        BrowserItemCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(BrowserItem.L3group)));
    }

    private bool FilterBrowserItems(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is BrowserItem check)
        {
            return check.Name.Contains(BrowserItemFilter);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name the `Expander` and then look it up in the template of the group item by its name or use the `VisualTreeHelper` to traverse the visual tree to find the `Expander`:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
  //When slider is moved, set the item in the list as active
  for (int index = 0; index < store.Browser.Count; index++)
  {
    BrowserItem browserItem  = store.Browser[index];

    if (index == e.NewValue)
    { 
      browserItem .Active = true;
      displayslider.Text = index.ToString();
      TreeViewSheets.ScrollIntoView(browserItem);

      if (TryGetExpanderOfItem(browserItem, out Expander expander))
      {
        expander.Active = true; 
      }
    }
    else
    {
      browserItem.Active = false;
    }
  }
}

private bool TryGetExpanderOfItem(object browserItem, out Expander expander)
{
  expander = null;

  CollectionViewGroup groupItem = this.TreeViewSheets.Items.Groups
    .OfType<CollectionViewGroup>()
    .FirstOrDefault(group => group.Items.Contains(browserItem));

  if (groupItem == null)
  {
    return false;
  }

  var groupContainer = this.TreeViewSheets.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(groupItem) as Control;
  expander = groupContainer?.Template.FindName("GroupExpander", groupContainer) as Expander;

  return expander != null;
}
```

---

### Find and expand all `Expander` elements in group

The following version returns all `Expander` elements in the visual tree starting from the selected group item:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
  //When slider is moved, set the item in the list as active
  for (int f = 0; f < store.Browser.Count; f++)
  {
    BrowserItem browserItem = store.Browser[f];

    if (f == e.NewValue)
    {
      browserItem.Active = true;
      displayslider.Text = f.ToString();
      TreeViewSheets.ScrollIntoView(browserItem);

      foreach (CollectionViewGroup collectionViewGroup in this.TreeViewSheets.Items.Groups
        .OfType<CollectionViewGroup>())
      {
        if (TryCollectParentGroups(collectionViewGroup, browserItem, out IList<CollectionViewGroup> groupPath))
        {
          foreach (Expander expander in EnumerateExpandersOfItem(groupPath))
          {
            expander.IsExpanded = true;
          }

          break;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      browserItem.Active = false;
    }
  }
}

private bool TryCollectParentGroups(CollectionViewGroup parentGroup, object referenceItem, out IList<CollectionViewGroup> groupPath)
{
  groupPath = new List<CollectionViewGroup>();
  foreach (object parentGroupItem in parentGroup.Items)
  {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(parentGroupItem, referenceItem))
    {
      groupPath = new List<CollectionViewGroup>() {parentGroup};
      return true;
    }

    if (parentGroupItem is CollectionViewGroup childGroup)
    {
      if (TryCollectParentGroups(childGroup, referenceItem, out IList<CollectionViewGroup> childGroupPath))
      {
        groupPath = childGroupPath;
        groupPath.Insert(0, parentGroup);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

private IEnumerable<Expander> EnumerateExpandersOfItem(IList<CollectionViewGroup> groupPath)
{
  if (!groupPath.Any())
  {
    return Enumerable.Empty<Expander>();
  }

  CollectionViewGroup rootGroup = groupPath.First();
  groupPath.RemoveAt(0);
  var groupItemContainer = this.TreeViewSheets.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(rootGroup) as GroupItem;
  return EnumerateGroupPath(groupItemContainer, groupPath);
}

private IEnumerable<Expander> EnumerateGroupPath(
  GroupItem groupItemContainer,
  IList<CollectionViewGroup> groupPath)
{
  groupItemContainer.ApplyTemplate();
  foreach (Expander expander in groupItemContainer.EnumerateVisualChildElements<Expander>())
  {
    yield return expander;

    if (!groupPath.Any())
    {
      yield break;
    }

    (expander.Content as ItemsPresenter).ApplyTemplate();
    if ((expander.Content as ItemsPresenter).TryFindVisualChildElement(out Panel childGroupsHost))
    {
      CollectionViewGroup currentGroupNode = groupPath.First();
      IEnumerable<GroupItem> childGroups = childGroupsHost.Children.OfType<GroupItem>();
      GroupItem childGroupInPath = childGroups.FirstOrDefault(group => ReferenceEquals(group.Content, currentGroupNode));
      if (childGroupInPath == null)
      {
        continue;
      }
      groupPath.RemoveAt(0);
      foreach (Expander childExpander in EnumerateGroupPath(childGroupInPath, groupPath))
      {
        yield return childExpander;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks BionicCode - I appriciate your response. I've amended the code, but it fails at the point expander.IsExpanded = true - with the error 'expander was null'... Do you know why this is? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I think the issue is that you code works, but it doesn't recursively search down the tree and only returns a value for the top level...

Comment: I don't know how your view is structured. i was expecting a list of group items where each group is expandable via a Expander. Inside this group are the items that you are selecting via the Slider. So I pick the top level group items, extract the Expander element and expand it programmatically. Don't know how this scenario differs from yours? I have tested the code and it works for my described scenario.

Comment: If `expander` is `null` then the element wasn't found. The above code relies on the `Expander` being named `x:Name="GroupExpander"`. This was chosen for simplicity. You can use the `VisualTreeHelper` instead to traverse the visual tree to search for the `Expander`.

Comment: According to the GroupStyle you have provided in your example, the Expander is the root element of the group item. There is no need to recursively drill into the visual tree, especially as the above example uses the element's name to let the template look up the element.

Comment: mmm... I've copied your code, but it still fails with a null - you can probably tell I'm new to WPF... the bit that causes the null is:      var groupItem = this.TreeViewSheets.Items.Groups.OfType<CollectionViewGroup>().FirstOrDefault(group => group.Items.Contains(browserItem));               but if I remove the group => group.Items.Contains(browserItem) bit it returns a CollectionViewGroupInternal... (I use the name 'GroupExpander' as you've suggested.)

Comment: I see. Are there items that are without a group? The code works like this: you activate a BrowserItem using the Slider - Slider value changed event is raised. We then get all groups of the ListView. We then lookup the activated BrowserItem. Once we get this item we try to find out in which of the groups it is contained. Once we found the group that contains the activated BrowserItem, we search the Expander in this group container's template by name and expand it. According to your observation there is no group that contains the currently tested BrowserItem -> are there items without a group?

Comment: When I look at your posted code I don't see any grouping. Is this happening in the MainWindowViewModel? How are you doing this? Are actually having groups? The code is not made robust. It just was meant to show the algorithm. I will update the code so that it won't break when there are no groups. That's why I commented the result with `// Can be null`. i was hoping you understand this comment as motivation to apply a null-check before referencing the result.

Comment: I still can't get this to work unfortunatly, I think it the group => group.Items.Contains(browserItem) which always returns null... I have found that if I execute this part it expands and contracts the top expander though (just doesn't find the others)            var topcontainer = this.TreeViewSheets.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(groupItem2) as Control;
           allExpanders.Add(topcontainer?.Template.FindName("GroupExpander", topcontainer) as Expander);

Comment: I also think part of the problem is that WPF shows the Expanders as CollectionViewGroups - which is maybe why the search doesn't find them.... I'm unsure if you can convert a CollectionViewGroup into an expander... There is a link at the top of the post which had the code if thats any help to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by top level expander? How many expanders does a single group have? I have described my expected visual tree when I described the algorithm in my previous comment. Do you have a different tree structure? I don't like to download the archive to my local machine. You should use GitHub or something similar and create a public repository. This way I can review your code online. You can't convert a CollectionViewGroup to Expander as those are completely unrelated types.

Comment: I have added an example, that you can run. If this still don't help, then please post: 1) how you create the collection 2) How you configure the grouping 3) complete the GroupStyle in case you are missing details

Comment: Thanks I'll try out your code. To answer your questions, I've editted my post to include the MainWindowViewModel class, this has a constructor that creates the groups using a CollectionViewSource (my appologies, I should have posted this code originally...)

Comment: The groups are created based on a collectionViewSource which looks at the original ObservableCollection (that contains BrowserItems) and sets up dynamic groups (expanders) which are displayed in the ListView.

Comment: Thats great - I can get that to work and it expands the headers as it should - Thanks for you help on this. One question though, I need to set the BrowserItems with several group headers which would create items in nested expanders - could I run the code to get the expander on an expander? Cheers.

Comment: When using nested Expanders, you could use recursion. The code will change slightly. Instead of using named Expander elements, you use the VisualTreeHelper to traverse the tree. I have updated the answer. But consider to switch to a TreeView instead. From your description this seems to be the proper control to use in your scenario.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think TChildren needs to be added to this bit as I've done here: public static IEnumerable EnumerateVisualChildElements<TChildren>(this DependencyObject parent) where TChildren : DependencyObject                Also, I get the error 'Control does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateVisualChildElements  on the return groupContainer.EnumerateVisualChildElements<Expander>(); line,

Comment: Sorry, the method `EnumerateVisualChildElements` was originally implemented as an extension method and has to be declared as member of  a static class. Let me fix it. I copied the class from my private code and modified it for this example without testing it afterwards (sloppy). I forgot that I had to add the static class definition as this is an extension method It's now fixed: add _HelperExtensions.cs_

Comment: Thanks, that cures the errors, but I now get one error on this code: public partial class MainWindow : Window  - the error is Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class.     I've not come across this error before and read on the internet doesn't help, do you have any thoughts on this? Cheers.

Comment: Have you defined the method `EnumerateVisualChildElements` in it's own static clas like the HelperExtensions class above?

Comment: Yes, I created a new Class file and copied the code into there heres what the file looks like: https://pastebin.com/87mq7DcE there are no errors with it

Comment: I think the issue is that the helper class is a static class and the containing class is not static... (from what I can work out from Google!)

Comment: Don't define the class nested to some other class. Move HelperExtensions class to its own file.

Comment: I see, you have done this  already. Then make sure you have deleted the original method from your previous attempt. It appears like there is still the reference to the previous method (the method without the static class). Then do a Clean Solution and Rebuild Solution. But to me looks like a wrong method reference.

Comment: OK. I've got rid of that error I believe, I started again so it was some issue with what I had written. I added some code to create a level of grouping expanders:                     for (int f = 0; f < GroupItems.Count; f++)
            {
                if (f <= 5) GroupItems[f].L2group = "test1";
                if (f > 5) GroupItems[f].L2group = "test2";

            }

Comment: I can't get the code to expand any expanders, because I believe the line in EnumerateExpandersOfItem:                CollectionViewGroup groupItem = this.TreeViewSheets.Items.Groups
              .OfType<CollectionViewGroup>()
              .FirstOrDefault(group => group.Items.Contains(browserItem));                  will only find a browser item if its in the top level of grouping - if its in the second level then a null is returned and it doesn't run the next part where it EnumeratesVisualChildElements...

Comment: I appriciate your help and patience with this!

Comment: I have updated the answer with modified version, which now supports nested groups.

Comment: Thanks for that. I get an error in regard to ItemsPresenter.TryFindVisualChildElement 'ItemsPresenter does not contain a definition for TryFindVisualChildElement'. Is there a method missing?

Comment: Hi, I found the TryFindVisualChildElement method on your Github! https://github.com/BionicCode - the routine now works a treat! Thanks for your help!